# Unable to deserialize XML file

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, deserialization

I am attempting to deserialize a XML file into .net objects.  I'm concerned the format of the file may be incorrect (however doubtful).  The file can contain a number of group with collections of sub groups.  I thought I built the classes to match that of the XML file.  Below are the classes, and the code to deserialize the XML.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim export As XMLExport

    Dim serializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(XMLExport))
    Dim fn As New FileStream("C:\temp\TEST_AP_20190426_040000.xml", FileMode.Open)
    export = serializer.Deserialize(fn)
    fn.Close()
End Sub

<XmlRoot("XMLExport")>
Public Class XMLExport
    <XmlElement("VoucherHeader")>
    Public Vouchers() As VoucherHeader
End Class

Public Class VoucherHeader
    <XmlElement("VoucherKey")> Public VoucherKey As String
    <XmlElement("VouchNo")> Public VoucherNo As String
    <XmlElement("VoucherTranNo")> Public VoucherTranNo As String
    <XmlElement("VoucherTranDate")> Public VoucherTranDate As Date
    <XmlElement("VoucherHdrCmnt")> Public VoucherHdrCmnt As String
    <XmlElement("VoucherTranAmt")> Public VoucherTranAmt As Double

    <XmlElement("VoucherDetail")>
    Public VoucherDetails() As VoucherDetail
End Class

Public Class VoucherDetail
    <XmlElement("VoucherLineGLAcctNo")> Public VoucherLineGLAcctNo As String
    <XmlElement("VoucherLineAmt")> Public VoucherLineAmt As String
    <XmlElement("ApplyFromTranID")> Public ApplyFromTranID As String
    <XmlElement("ApplyFromTranDate")> Public ApplyFromTranDate As String
    <XmlElement("CheckMemos")> Public CheckMemos As String
    <XmlElement("PmtAmt")> Public PmtAmount As String
    <XmlElement("VoucherLineKey")> Public VoucherLineKey As String
    <XmlElement("VoucherLineDistKey")> Public VoucherLineDistKey As String
    <XmlElement("ApplyToVoucherKey")> Public ApplyToVoucherKey As String
    <XmlElement("EntryNo")> Public EntryNo As String
End Class
```

An example of the XML I can receive looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<XMLExport>
    <VoucherHeader>
    <VoucherKey>1242550</VoucherKey>
    <VouchNo>0000000976</VouchNo>
    <VoucherTranNo>15W030B041619</VoucherTranNo>
    <VoucherTranDate>2019-04-16T00:00:00</VoucherTranDate>
    <VoucherHdrCmnt>Acct 26-05-39-6922 1</VoucherHdrCmnt>
    <VoucherTranAmt>44.090</VoucherTranAmt>
    <VoucherDetail>
        <VoucherLineGLAcctNo>72100</VoucherLineGLAcctNo>
        <VoucherLineAmt>44.090</VoucherLineAmt>
        <ApplyFromTranID>0000001906-CK</ApplyFromTranID>
        <ApplyFromTranDate>2019-04-25T00:00:00</ApplyFromTranDate>
        <CheckMemos>Acct 26-05-39-6922 1</CheckMemos>
        <PmtAmt>444.090</PmtAmt>
        <VoucherLineKey>1734668</VoucherLineKey>
        <VoucherLineDistKey>1734670</VoucherLineDistKey>
        <ApplyToVoucherKey>12344</ApplyToVoucherKey>
        <EntryNo>1</EntryNo>
    </VoucherDetail>
    <VoucherDetail>
        <VoucherLineGLAcctNo>72100</VoucherLineGLAcctNo>
        <VoucherLineAmt>44.090</VoucherLineAmt>
        <ApplyFromTranID>0000001906-CK</ApplyFromTranID>
        <ApplyFromTranDate>2019-04-25T00:00:00</ApplyFromTranDate>
        <CheckMemos>Acct 26-05-39-6922 1</CheckMemos>
        <PmtAmt>46.090</PmtAmt>
        <VoucherLineKey>1734368</VoucherLineKey>
        <VoucherLineDistKey>1734670</VoucherLineDistKey>
        <ApplyToVoucherKey>1242550</ApplyToVoucherKey>
        <EntryNo>1</EntryNo>
    </VoucherDetail>
    <VoucherDetail>
        <VoucherLineGLAcctNo>72100</VoucherLineGLAcctNo>
        <VoucherLineAmt>44.090</VoucherLineAmt>
        <ApplyFromTranID>0000001906-CK</ApplyFromTranID>
        <ApplyFromTranDate>2019-04-25T00:00:00</ApplyFromTranDate>
        <CheckMemos>Acct 43436922 1</CheckMemos>
        <PmtAmt>44.090</PmtAmt>
        <VoucherLineKey>1734668</VoucherLineKey>
        <VoucherLineDistKey>1734670</VoucherLineDistKey>
        <ApplyToVoucherKey>1242550</ApplyToVoucherKey>
        <EntryNo>1</EntryNo>
    </VoucherDetail>
    </VoucherHeader>
    <VoucherHeader>
        <VoucherKey>1242552</VoucherKey>
        <VouchNo>0000000977</VouchNo>
        <VoucherTranNo>14483</VoucherTranNo>
        <VoucherTranDate>2019-04-11T00:00:00</VoucherTranDate>
        <VoucherHdrCmnt>Cust 2449 Spring 2019 Inspection</VoucherHdrCmnt>
        <VoucherTranAmt>975.000</VoucherTranAmt>
        <VoucherDetail>
            <VoucherLineGLAcctNo>70200</VoucherLineGLAcctNo>
            <VoucherLineAmt>975.000</VoucherLineAmt>
            <ApplyFromTranID>0000001905-CK</ApplyFromTranID>
            <ApplyFromTranDate>2019-04-25T00:00:00</ApplyFromTranDate>
            <CheckMemos>Cust 2449</CheckMemos>
            <PmtAmt>975.000</PmtAmt>
            <VoucherLineKey>1734669</VoucherLineKey>
            <VoucherLineDistKey>1734671</VoucherLineDistKey>
            <ApplyToVoucherKey>1242552</ApplyToVoucherKey>
            <EntryNo>1</EntryNo>
        </VoucherDetail>
    </VoucherHeader>
    <VoucherHeader>
        <VoucherKey>1242553</VoucherKey>
        <VouchNo>0000000978</VouchNo>
        <VoucherTranNo>354112</VoucherTranNo>
        <VoucherTranDate>2019-04-15T00:00:00</VoucherTranDate>
        <VoucherHdrCmnt>Cust 3238</VoucherHdrCmnt>
        <VoucherTranAmt>135.000</VoucherTranAmt>
        <VoucherDetail>
            <VoucherLineGLAcctNo>70500</VoucherLineGLAcctNo>
            <VoucherLineAmt>135.000</VoucherLineAmt>
            <ApplyFromTranID>0000001904-CK</ApplyFromTranID>
            <ApplyFromTranDate>2019-04-25T00:00:00</ApplyFromTranDate>
            <CheckMemos>Cust 3238</CheckMemos>
            <PmtAmt>135.000</PmtAmt>
            <VoucherLineKey>1734695</VoucherLineKey>
            <VoucherLineDistKey>1734697</VoucherLineDistKey>
            <ApplyToVoucherKey>1242553</ApplyToVoucherKey>
            <EntryNo>1</EntryNo>
        </VoucherDetail>
    </VoucherHeader>
</XMLExport>
```

I was hoping to iterate through the collection of "Vouchers" since there can be multiple VoucherHeaders, and within each Voucher Header, iterate through the VoucherDetails.

I have attempted to change the XML Decorations on the classes, items, etc., but now the code will fail on the  `serializer.Deserialize(fn)` line with the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in XMLReader.exe
>   Additional information:
>   Unable to cast object of type 'XMLReader.XMLExport' to type 'XMLReader.XMLExport[]'.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#

Comment: You're right, I removed the [tag:C#] tag.

Comment: Sorry - I'd take code in c# or vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make the following changes:

**(1)** The root element is not defined as the container of an array.  Change the declaration to be a single reference to `XMLExport`.

```
Dim export As XMLExport
```

**(2)** `XmlRoot` will be ignored in the places where you've applied it.  The only place where it will have an effect is on the `XMLExport` class because that's the root of the document.  The name matches the class so there's no difference.  This is only important if you want flexibility in the class name without changing the element name.

**(3)** Instead of `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem`, use `XmlElement`.  The serializer already knows it's an array.  With only `XmlElement`, it'll use that element name for an inline list of elements instead elements in a single parent element.

```
<XmlRoot("XMLExport")>
Public Class XMLExport
    <XmlElement("VoucherHeader")>
    Public Vouchers() As VoucherHeader
End Class
```

**(4)** Same thing for voucher details.

```
Public Class VoucherHeader
    '...

    <XmlElement("VoucherDetail")>
    Public VoucherDetails() As VoucherDetail
End Class
```

**(5)** In `VoucherHeader`, you have three properties of type `Double` but the content is text or a date/time.  Change the types like so:

```
<XmlElement("VoucherTranNo")> Public VoucherTranNo As String
<XmlElement("VoucherTranDate")> Public VoucherTranDate As Date
<XmlElement("VoucherHdrCmnt")> Public VoucherHdrCmnt As String
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch in #5 - was a copy paste error when building the class.I made the changes as you suggested and I updated the code in my post.  I'm now receiving the exception: There is an error in XML document (2, 2).  I have a little concern for the format of the XML file given to me...or there is still something wrong with my classes.

Comment: If you're getting that exception, there's a mismatch in the root element name. Your code no longer matches what's posted.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and made the fix.  I just updated the class objects with exactly what I have, including your suggestions.  When you say a mismatch in the root element name are you speaking of the  <XmlElement("VouchNo")> Public VoucherNo As String or something else?  I truly appreciate your help on this, I've been staring at it so long, it helps to have another set of eyes take a look.

Comment: I  found my bug!

Comment: Helps if I serialize the correct objects.  I was playing with various versions of the code and serialized the wrong object.  I made the corrections to the code above and it worked!  Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I had a feeling that something else had changed. That's great news that it's fixed!